# Bluemix Watson Speech-To-Text Priority Option

Tags: ibm-cloud, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

Just wondering if there is a priority option for Watson's speech-to-text service that would yield faster translation results. We would be willing to pay a premium to receive the fastest results possible and just wondering if there are provisions for that kind of service.

I'm assuming not as I would expect it to be included on the price list, but if anyone is aware if this is available or if it might someday be available, I would be interested.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are open source packages which provide much faster response time with comparable accuracy, they are definitely a solution if you experience latency issues.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is **NO**.

In order to get faster translations make sure:

1. When calling `/recognize`, you are using WebSockets and not the REST API.
2. You network is not introducing significant latency (are you in the US?, china?)
3. You are sending the right amount of data. Sometimes there is no need to use a large sampling rate.